# How can I show 2 different activities of one application at recent applications?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to show 2 different activities of one app at recent apps by calling 2 different activities like the image below.
How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Hello again :) Please check if this is what you're looking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866998/how-to-keep-multiple-activities-of-the-same-app-in-the-recent-apps-list

Comment: Thank youu it is true answer again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **API Level 21 or above**, it can simply be accomplished by setting the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT) in the intent.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
```

---

If your minimum API level is **less than 21**, you can make use of the activity attribute [`taskAffinity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#aff) in the manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ActivityOne"
    android:taskAffinity="app.two" />

<activity
    android:name="com.example.ActivityTwo"
    android:taskAffinity="app.two" />
```

After setting different affinities, launching the activities as `singleInstance` or setting the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) will make the two activities appear separately in the recents.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ActivityTwo"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:taskAffinity="app.two" />
```

OR

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my minSdkVersion is 16 and taskAffinity is working.

Comment: Great! I have updated the answer.